# Probability density function with large mu and sigma values?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, normal-distribution

I am using the following function :

```
 pd=makedist('normal',mu,sigma);
 y = pdf(pd,speed)
```

The size of `mu` and `sigma` is 50x1 and `X` size is 3000x1. passing one value of mu,sigma and speed at a time, I am getting the output. But how I can pass all these values at the same time so that at the end I will get a data set containing all `y` values?

I think I have to use a `for` loop but am unsure how to do it.

Comment: ohh sry i did not realise that I did this (I am new to this stackflow)..... Please give me this option again. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mu = rand(50,1);
sigma = rand(50,1);
speed = rand(3000,1);
y = zeros(numel(mu),numel(speed));

for k = 1:numel(mu)
    pd = makedist('normal',mu(k),sigma(k));
    y(k,:) = pdf(pd,speed);  %store in for loop
end
```

By initialising the output one can easily double-loop to calculate all components. Your ouput is now indexed as `y(mu/sigma,speed)`, thus the first index corresponds to the `mu/sigma` pair and the second to the `speed` entry used.

Comment: thank your for your help but while running this sample of your code in matlab I m getting following error  'The following error occurred converting from prob.NormalDistribution to double:
Conversion to double from prob.NormalDistribution is not possible.'   any solution..??

Comment: Oh, that means you can't actually get the `pd` this way. Do you want to have the `pd` at all, or just the `y` values? Just the `y` values is lots easier. I changed to code to not save `pd`

Comment: I finally need y value because that y value is going to give me the output. but how you will get y value without having pd values because as you can see that both are related...??

Comment: I do use the `pd` values, as you can see I calculate them within the outer loop. I don't save them however, since it is a cumbersome file-type. Please check the code first, because it does use everything.

Comment: Yes I can see... So could you modify the correct code so that I check the output values whether I am getting correct one or not. Because after running this code y and pd values is showing zero in everywhere...

Comment: Adriaan, see my edit to your code, I think it's more fast and clean this way.

Comment: @EBH thanks. As I don't have MATLAB installed here I wasn't sure `makedist` accepted vectors as input. Better indeed.

Comment: @EBH  thank you for helping me. Cheers :).  lastly, could you tell me what is the name of that method which you used ..??  so that I can read more about this...??

Comment: And please upvote my question if you understand this question properly.. :)

Comment: @Sujal I don't know what method you talk about :-/

Comment: Thanks I understand this code now properly. I have last question related to this  why u use for loop with mu..?? any special reason .. why you don't use sigma for example...??

Comment: @Sujal you don't iterate over `mu`, but over `1:numel(mu)`, which means "1 to the number of elements in `mu`, doesn't matter what `mu` contains. `mu` and `sigma` are both the same size, so there is no difference in writing `1:numel(sigma)`

Comment: Thank you @EBH now I understand